# An Elegant Way To Find A Free Port In Scala

Tags: scala

I reworked the Java code to find a free port that I found here => https://gist.github.com/vorburger/3429822#file-gistfile1-java to use in Scala

```
def findFreePort(): Int = {
    var ss: ServerSocket = null

    try {
      ss = new ServerSocket(0)
      ss.getLocalPort
    } finally {
      ss.close()
    }
  }
```

However, it looks very ugly with var assigned to `null`. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You could wrap it in an [option](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) and use `Some(ss)` and `None`.

Comment: Avoid questions that allow for opinionated fuzzy answers. "What's an elegant / better way to do X?" is off topic, but "How to avoid `null`?" is on-topic.

Comment: @k0pernikus Language of the question aside, such cases are really tricky. And almost everyone in Scala community has faced these at least few times.

Comment: `Try(new ServerSocket(0)).map(_.getLocalPort).toOption` The finally is a bit more tricky, I would recommend you to use something like a [**Resource**](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/cats/effect/Resource.html)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez as I understand, when you call ```new ServerSocket(0)```, it can open a socket connection and then throw an exception, so you need to close it handling the exception... Wrapping in ```Try```does not offer it. COrrect me if I am wrong

Comment: @ClassNotFoundException you are probably correct, that is why I said the `close` was _tricky_. That is why I suggested `Resource`. However, if you aren't using **cats** and you have Scala `2.13` then `Using` sounds like the best option.

Comment: The solution is quite simple, use val ss = new ServerSocket(); val port = ss.getLocalPort; ss.close(); return port. If new ServerSocket() throws, there's nothing to clean up, because it won't have returned anything, so there's nothing you can close, you actually have a bug in your code where you're not checking if ss is null. and getLocalPort doesn't throw, so it doesn't need to be done in a try/finally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [Using](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Using$.html):

```
scala> import scala.util.{Using, Try}

scala> def findFreePort(): Try[Int] = Using(new ServerSocket(0)) (_.getLocalPort)
def findFreePort(): util.Try[Int]

scala> findFreePort()
val res1: util.Try[Int] = Success(51865)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Using might be not available in older scala versions.

Answer (score 0):

The original implementation seems wrong to me. If the `ServerSocket` constructor fails, `ss` will still be `null`, and the `close` call will fail with a `NullPointerException`. Just [run this Scastie snippet to be convinced](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4KQGajDoSu2N06kznECxIA).

Unless I'm missing something, it's then best to write your snippet as

```scala
val port: Option[Int] = Try(new ServerSocket(0).close()).map(_.getLocalPort).toOption
```